# Enable two-finger zoom in InChart mode of TeeChart for Android

Tags: android, zooming, teechart

According to the documentation of the evaluation version of TeeChart for Android ("TeeChartJavaAndroid_2013Eval"), zooming with two-finger touch can be enabled for `ZoomStyle.FULLCHART` mode:

> FullChart mode
>
> **Scroll**
>   Touch a finger to the screen and drag it in the direction that you would like the entire Chart to move.
>
> **Zoom**
>   To Zoom, touch two fingers to the screen at the centre location you wish to zoom and drag the fingers apart. To Unzoom invert the procedure, touch the screen at any two outer locations and drag your fingers togther before releasing them from the screen.

Nevertheless, for InChart mode it uses a one-click drag zoom and scroll approach.
Is there any way to enable the two-finger zooming for InChart mode?.

Comment: To activate FullChart, so you can pinch for zooming, you have to use the call: `tChart1.getZoom().setZoomStyle(ZoomStyle.FULLCHART);`

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo in my initial question. I meant to ask about use pinch for zooming in InChart mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand you want to use pinch gesture to make the chart rescale the axes, right?

The problem here is that, between the start and the end of the pinch gesture, each time the device detects a movement in one of your fingers. And, if we rescale and repaint the chart each time a movement is detected, we'll repaint the chart many times, slowing the process.

In some versions of TeeChart there's a special Zoom style that plays with images to do this zoom effect, making it faster. But I'm afraid this style isn't available in TeeChart Java for Android yet.

Comment: Thanks, @Yeray. Do you know if they're planning to add it to TeeChart Java for Android soon?

Comment: Can't say that. You can follow the Steema's twitter, facebook, the support forum or the RSS news feed for new release announcements. And you can check what's implemented on each new release looking at the public release notes: https://www.steema.com/versioninfo/java